# _includes/forms documentation on field types

Tags: plugin-development, form, documentation

I'm trying to find any documentation on the usable forms from  `{% import "_includes/forms" as forms %}`
so for example I have no idea what the difference is between `elementSelect` and `select` or how I get the options in there

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5):

For anyone looking for more information, you can find all of the form macros for _includes/forms here:

```
/craft/app/templates/_includes/forms.html
```

and the child templates here:

```
/craft/app/templates/_includes/forms/<filename>
```

Answer (score 1):

There currently is no documentation for Craft's own template includes and macros.

Your best bet is to do a global search through the app folder and see how Craft is using them internally.

Comment: Is this still the case?

I am currently working through the use of a select field in a plugin.

Is there a format through which I could help provide some documentation for the benefit of the CMS user base?

Comment: Is still there is no documentation of craft available macros.